# React Native - How to render text that has breaklines "\n"

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to find a way to render texts that come from the database with their breaklines "\n".

[image: app]

How can a change the "\n" to the actual breaklines?

Comment: Since it is HTML, you can replace all occurances "\n" with "<br />", using `myDatabaseStr.replace("\n", "<br />");`

Comment: @sme It's not ReactJS, it's React Native, so it doesn't have HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this approach.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Main extends Component {
  renderText() {
    const textFromDB = 'This text\nfrom\ndatabase.'.split('\n');
    const rendered = textFromDB.map(x => <Text>{x}</Text>);

    return rendered;
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView>
          {this.renderText()}
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

// skip these lines if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent(
  'AwesomeProject',
  () => Main);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Wisnu answer I kinda found out how to do it, because his approach didn't work for me.

```
function renderTextWithBreakLines(text) {
    return text.split(`\n`).map((txt, i) => <Text key={i}>{ txt }{ '\n' }</Text>)
}
```

**And a shorter method would be:**

```
const renderTextWithBreakLines = text => text.split(`\n`).map((txt, i) => <Text key={i}>{ txt }{ '\n' }</Text>);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your text inside `{}` like so

```
<Text>{`Large Room~\nFully Furnished`}</Text>
```

Or declare your text as a variable and render like so

```
const someText = "Large Room\nFully Furnished"
<Text>{someText}</Text>
```